# Текст со ссылками в AlertDialog TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, link

есть два активити нужно в первом активити реализовать кастомный AlertDialog, диалог вроде получился но ссылки стали не кликабильными, помогите пожалуйста,

вот код из xml файла второго активити, в нем один TextView, в котором текст @string/about2

```
<string name="about2">Developed by <i><a href="google.ru">Google </a></i></string>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about2"
    android:id="@+id/textView_About"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

в java коде этого активити прописал код чтоб ссылки стали кликабильными и все работает правильно, но при добавлении кастомного AlertDialog ссылки перестают быть кликабильными, помогите пожалуйста

```
     TextView clickableTextLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_About);
    clickableTextLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

вот код AlertDialog

```
               View myView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.about, null); //имя кастомной xml

                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setView(myView);
                builder.setTitle("About");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //action to do
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
                alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего должно помочь вызывание метода `setLinksClickable(true)` над `TextView`.